# sed add line to end of range or end of file

Tags: sed, sh

I am trying to add a string at the end of the range using sed.

```
$ cat test.fl
TITLE OF FILE

first 1
second 2
third 3
fourth 4
fifth 5
sixth 6
seventh 7
eighth 8
ninth 9
first 1.1
second 1.2
third 1.3
fourth 1.4
fifth 1.5
sixth 1.6
seventh 1.7
eighth 1.8
ninth 1.9
```

I need to add a line to the end of the range. Let the range be limited by the words `first` and number, then I would like to get something like:

```
TITLE OF FILE

first 1
second 2
third 3
fourth 4
fifth 5
sixth 6
seventh 7
eighth 8
ninth 9
zero 0

first 1.1
second 1.2
third 1.3
fourth 1.4
fifth 1.5
sixth 1.6
seventh 1.7
eighth 1.8
ninth 1.9
```

I tried to use a construction like this

```
sed -e "/^first.*1$/,/^first.*/ { /^first.*1$/! {/^first.*/izero 0" -e "}}" ./test.fl
```

`/^first.*1$/,/^first.*/` - range from **first 1** to **first 1.1**;
`{ /^first.*1$/!` - not apply for start range line;
`{/^first.*/izero 0\n" -e "}` - add before **first 1.1** line "zero 0"

But not working for me. Of course, variables will be used in the added lines.

Experiments have shown that there is still a difference whether there is a lower bound of the range or it is the end of the file. I would like to be able to add a string in both cases. The more attempts I make, the more confused I get.

Comment: You don't need a range. Just match the end of the block and add a line after it. Or the beginning of the next block and insert before it.

Comment: @Barmar , thanks for answering. yes, I could give up ranges if the data set in blocks between first x was known in advance. I don't even know if there are blocks after the one I'm changing.

Comment: @Irbis you should be using single quotes around your script, not double. It's extremely important to always use single quotes around all strings in shell, including scripts, unless you **need** double quotes or no quotes - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes to learn the difference and when to use each.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/first/{:b;n;//!bb;s/.*/zero 0\n\n&/;ba}' file
```

Find a line which contains `first`, print and fetch the next.

Repeat until another line containing `first`, then using substitution, insert a line `zero 0` and a blank line.

Repeat.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me an idea. By specifying in the initial search parameters, you can choose which block to add the zero 0 string to. But what if this block is the last one (as first 1.1)? `sed "/first 1/{:b;n;/^first.*/!bb;s/.*/zero 0\n\n&/;:c;n;bc;q}" test.fl`

Comment: @Irbis I'm not sure what you mean but perhaps something like `sed ':a;/first/{:b;$bc;n;//!bb;:c;s/.*/zero 0\n\n&/;ba}' file`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, etc., etc. Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    ($1 == "first") && (pnf > 0) { print "" }
    { print; pnf=NF }
    END { if (pnf > 0) print "" }
' test.fl
TITLE OF FILE

first 1
second 2
third 3
fourth 4
fifth 5
sixth 6
seventh 7
eighth 8
ninth 9

first 1.1
second 1.2
third 1.3
fourth 1.4
fifth 1.5
sixth 1.6
seventh 1.7
eighth 1.8
ninth 1.9
```

The above assumes you really do want a blank line at the end of the file and that you don't want another blank line added if one already exists there or before a "first" line.